# Use a custom control from a folder in my project?

Tags: wpf, controls, directory

I'd like to organize my controls in folders so that they won't be cluttered, but how do I use the control through XAML? I tried this to no avail:

```
xmlns:controls="folder name"
```

**EDIT:**
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:ProjectName.FolderName"
```

Example:

[image]

Namespace declaration:

```
xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:ContextMenuStyle.MyCustomControls"
```

Using control `UserControl1.xaml` from `MyCustomControls` folder:

```
<controls:UserControl1 />
```

Comment: I keep getting the error "The type or namespace name 'Controls' does not exist in the namespace 'Project' (are you missing an assembly reference?)"

Comment: @leaf68 can you make screenshot as I did?

Comment: @leaf68 try rebuild the solution.

Comment: I've rebuilt several times and it doesn't seem to fix it. The control has a property "Custom Tool Namespace" which I tried leaving it blank, and adding my project's namespace but neither worked as well

Comment: I figured it out, I had renamed my folder earlier on and apparently I had to rename it in the XAML code and the namespace in the .cs file. After that, this code works, thanks :)